# 'Color blindness' or 'colorblindness', and 'color blind' or 'colorblind'?

Tags: word-choice

It seems like a lot of sources use different things. Is there a proper format for `color blind`/`colorblind` and `color blindness`/`colorblindness`?

Comment: Sorry shouldn't have included both. What I meant was, two words or one word?

Comment: To which (*a lot of*) sources are you referring?

Comment: @WeatherVane By “a lot of sources” I meant various articles, papers, and other media that I read, not sources on which way to write it.

Comment: FYI, the modern term is "color deficient". https://www.aoa.org/patients-and-public/eye-and-vision-problems/glossary-of-eye-and-vision-conditions/color-deficiency. As a side effect, this removes the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Google NGram search of British sources](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=colour%20blind%2Ccolourblind%2Ccolourblindness%2Ccolour%20blindness&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccolour%20blind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccolourblind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccolourblindness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccolour%20blindness%3B%2Cc0) with the appropriate spelling reveals a strong preference for the open compound *colour blindness* and the corresponding adjective *colour blind*.

[image]

A [similar search of American sources](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=color%20blind%2Ccolorblind%2Ccolorblindness%2Ccolor%20blindness&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccolor%20blind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccolorblind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccolorblindness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccolor%20blindness%3B%2Cc0) shows the same preference for the open compound *color blindness*, but starting in the 1990s, a preference for *colorblind* over *color blind*.

[image]

Comment: I don't get this NGram business. If the majority of people are writing "I should of ..." does the popular mistake make it right?

Comment: An NGram searches published sources, not internet ephemera, and is as close as you can get to usage trends among educated elites.

Comment: @WeatherVane [Descriptivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_description) is a perfectly acceptable way to approach grammar (and [some books](https://news.collinselt.com/prescriptive-vs-descriptive-approaches-to-grammar/) do take this approach).

Comment: @Laurel I do get that. Like everybody else who speaks their native language, I was only shown "grammar" after I learnt to speak and write it from my family and peers. That grammar is a formalised way to teach another language to non-native speakers.

Comment: I decided to mark this one the correct answer because it shows both English and British spellings, as well as numerical data and historical comparisons too. The other answers are also correct as far as I can tell, there is no strictly correct way, but colorblind and color blindness seem to be the most used choices.

Answer (score 1):

@Weather Vane is right.  Not a matter for dictionaries but for style guides. Pick one, and stick to it. No-one will be confused whichever choice you make. 
There is no "proper" in this context.

Comment: **Pick one, and stick to it.** Well put, Jeremy. There is a very common trend for newly coined expressions to begin as separate words, sometimes going via a hyphenated stage, then becoming accepted as single words. The best you can do so you are internally consistent (most important) and approximate current fashions (desirable) is to pick one reference source and look it up whenever in doubt. When writing a long document, I record what I find whenever I look up something in case I need it again.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm **colorblind**, you see. All Cats Are Gray."  Andre Alice Norton.

http://www.dictionary.net/colorblind
http://www.spellcheck.net/colorblind#

though **color-blind** and **color blind** are also frequently seen and accepted:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/color-blind

colorblindness is commonly 2 words: **color blindness**.